# Как можно изменить место блока jQuery, JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<div class="ms-left">
    <div class="ms-section" id="left1">
        <h1>Left 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="ms-section" id="left2">
        <h1>Left 2 </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="ms-section" id="left3">
        <h1>Left 3</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="ms-right">
    <div class="ms-section" id="right1">
        <h1>Right 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="ms-section" id="right2">
        <h1>Right 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="ms-section" id="right3">
        <h1>Right 3</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как здесь можно изменить место блоков по `id=right`* после 1000px рас. экрана? и каждый блок `id=right`* должен стоять после блока `id=left`*

Например:

```
    <div class="ms-section" id="left1">
       <h1>Left 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="ms-section" id="right1">
        <h1>Right 1</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="ms-section" id="left2">
       <h1>Left 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="ms-section" id="right2">
        <h1>Right 2</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: @media (scc) - вам не подойдет?

Comment: подойдет, но как?

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .left,.right {
     float:left;
     width:50%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 999px) {
  .left,.right {
     float:left;
     width:100%;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="ms-section left" >
    <h1>Left 1</h1>
</div>
<div class="ms-section right" >
    <h1>Right 1</h1>
</div>
<div class="ms-section left" >
    <h1>Left 2</h1>
</div>
<div class="ms-section right" >
    <h1>Right 2</h1>
</div>
```